# Get Linkedin OAuth2 access token from token and token secret

Tags: java, linkedin-api, access-token, linkedin-j

I am using [linkedin-j](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/). I am using Oauth flow as following to fetch token and token secret.

```
    LinkedInRequestToken liRequestToken = (LinkedInRequestToken) request.getSession().getAttribute("liRequestToken");
    LinkedInOAuthService linkedin = (LinkedInOAuthService) request.getSession().getAttribute("linkedin");
    String oauth_verifier = request.getParameter("oauth_verifier");
    try{
        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = linkedin.getOAuthAccessToken(liRequestToken, oauth_verifier);
        insertLinkedinAccessTokenToDataBase(accessToken.getToken(), accessToken.getTokenSecret()));
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Which I can later use for fetching user data.
But some Linkedin API are not available in linked-j (i.e. https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?is-company-admin=true&oauth2_access_token=###########################################################)
How can I get this oauth2_access_token from token and token secret to call these APIs mannually?